# What is the best way to track requester and requestee for changes in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `Users` table. Any user can make a multiple `reservations`. I am trying to track reservation edits on `reservation_changes` table. A user can either be a `requester` or `requestee` for the reservation changes. What is the best way to track them in `reservation_changes` table?

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
 has_many :reservations
end

class Reservation < ApplicationRecord
 belogs_to :user
 has_many :reservation_changes
end

class ReservationChanges < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :reservation
end
```

Expected Output:

```
user = User.last
another_user = User.first
```

After updating the reservations by `user` and requesting for changes. I want to record `user` as requester and `another_user` as requestee.

```
user.requester => user.id
user.requestee => another_user.id
```

Comment: There are lots of gems for versioning that can help you with this. See https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/Active_Record_Versioning for a list.

Comment: Provide a view example you would like to happen. The way you said seems it has multiples ways to be done. You may use pseudo code also. Waiting...

Comment: @PauloFelipeSouza Updated the expected output.

Comment: Did Les Nightingill's answer solve your question? If not, I'll provide here the official reference for this answer https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html, topic 4.1.2.5 - foreign_key. Another possiblitity to try is: "the has many :through association" from topic 2.4 from the same link. Your example is very very closed to this one. Remember, as you probably saw on the first topic, rails will not create a migration for you unless you do it.

Answer (score 0):

A reservation change needs to store the requester and requestee, so:

```rb
class ReservationChange < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :reservation
  belongs_to :requester, class_name: User
  belongs_to :requestee, class_name: User
end
```

And you'll need to add request_id and requestee_id columns to the reservation_changes table in a migration.